# Magento 2 : Call phtml file after Customer Account Information Admin side?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento-admin

I want to call one custom phtml file after Customer Edit Account Information Form.

Currently, I have tried below way so phtml file called but it's display on every customer edit tab?

> 1. Vendor/Extension/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View\Custom"
                   name="customer_edit_tab_view_custom"
                   template="Vendor_Extension::customer/view/custom.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 2. Vendor/Extension/view/adminhtml/templates/customer/view/custom.phtml

```
<div>Testdata</div>
```

> 3. Vendor/Extension/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/View/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace Magecomp\Googlemaplocation\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View;

class Custom extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Custom Label');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Custom Label');
    }
}
```

Now, Testdata display after every Customer Edit tab content I want to display Testdata only after Account Information form.

How to do this ?

Comment: you want to add a field in the account information tab last.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to following things.

> 1. Vendor/Extension/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

Add code like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <fieldset name="customer">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
             <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View\Custom</argument>
         </htmlContent>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

And into block file added code like this :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View;
 
class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'customer\view\custom.phtml';
}
```

Comment: i will add code but not working all tabs show testdata